# Allow tags to be edited on 'moved' questions

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags, migration, moderation

From [this Uservoice Item](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/223202-allow-tags-to-be-edited-on-moved-questions):

If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004078/is-there-anyway-to-determine-who-dropped-a-table-closed) there's a tag called 'ass-kicking' that no one can get rid of since the question was locked and moved to [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) . I'm not sure what the resolution could be, but either:

1. Allow 10Kers to edit locked questions to remove tags (for questions that have been moved?)
2. Allow us to flag said questions so people that can remove tags or edit questions that are moved can do that.

The bottom line is that I don't think it's a good idea to create a system where I could potentially have a tag last forever because no one but 4 people can get rid of it.

Comment: The whole moving questions thing needs some polish, including what it leaves behind on the originating site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flag it for moderator attention, and we can deal with the locked questions no problem.

Comment: The flag button appears to be missing from moved questions. I guess I'll have to flag some other question, and include the URL of the question needing attention! Hooray for inconveniences.